# Getting Facebook user access token from Facebook SDK for .Net in ASP.Net MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm mostly using a template from a MVC app that sets up the Facebook login and register process. I can register and log in using facebook, but when I register I want to pull additional data (gender, birthday, etc) from the Facebook user so I don't have to ask them to do it manually. This will be done in .Net, so I'm trying to use the Facebook .Net SDK but I don't know how to get the users access token from the template code that Visual studiio has set up for me. Here is my code. Take a look at var accessToken = ??
"var info" has some data coming back from facebook, like the provider key, but no access token or user id. This method below is after the user has entered in their Facebook credentials.

```
 [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manage");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
            var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
            }
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email, MembershipCreated = DateTime.Now }; //{ UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email, MembershipCreated = DateTime.Now, Gender = model.Gender, Birthdate = birthdayDateTime };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

                    //try to create profile here
                    var accessToken= //need to get access token here!!!
                    FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

                    dynamic fbUser = client.Get("https://www.facebook.com/" + info.DefaultUserName);

                    if (returnUrl == "/Account/Register")
                    {
                        returnUrl = "/Home";
                    }
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: How do you get the token?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Facebook Access token as a Claim.
In the Startup.Auth.cs file add the something like below to save the access token to ClaimsIdentity.

```
var facebookAuthenticationOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AppId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Test_Facebook_AppId"],
                AppSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Test_Facebook_AppSecret"],
                //SendAppSecretProof = true,
                Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
                    {
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            };
```

Then you can retrieve the accesstoken from the claims identity, whenever you need it.

```
private async Task<UserProfile> getFacebookUserProfileInfo(string userId)
        {
            var claimsIdentity = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            if (claimsIdentity != null)
            {
                var facebookAccessTokenClaim = claimsIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type.Equals("FacebookAccessToken"));
                if (facebookAccessTokenClaim != null)
                {
                    var fb = new FacebookClient(facebookAccessTokenClaim.Value);
                    dynamic myInfo = fb.Get("/v2.2/me?fields=id,name,gender,about,location,link,picture.type(large)");
                    var pictureUrl = myInfo.ContainsKey("picture") ? myInfo["picture"].data["url"] : null;
                    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pictureUrl))
                    {
                        string filename = Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/Uploads/user_profile_pictures/{0}.jpeg", userId));

                        await DownloadProfileImage(new Uri(pictureUrl),                     return new UserProfile
                    {
                        Gender = myInfo.ContainsKey("gender") ? myInfo["gender"] : null,
                        FacebookPage = myInfo.ContainsKey("link") ? myInfo["link"] : null,
                        ProfilePicture = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(pictureUrl) ? string.Format("/Uploads/user_profile_pictures/{0}.jpeg", userId) : null,
                        City = myInfo.ContainsKey("location") ? myInfo["location"]["name"] : null,
                        About = myInfo.ContainsKey("about") ? myInfo["about"] : null
                    };
                }
            }
            return null;
        }filename);
                    }
```